# Could not find implicit value for parameter x

Tags: scala, types, implicit

Just when I thought I understood the basics of Scala's type system... :/

I'm trying to implement a class that reads the contents of a file and outputs a set of records. A record might be a single line, but it could also be a block of bytes, or anything. So what I'm after is a structure that allows the type of Reader to imply the type of the Record, which in turn will imply the correct Parser to use.

This structure works as long as `MainApp.records(f)` only returns one type of Reader. As soon as it can return more, I get this error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter parser

I think the problem lies with the typed trait definitions at the top, but I cannot figure out how to fix the issue...

```
// Core traits
trait Record[T]
trait Reader[T] extends Iterable[Record[T]]
trait Parser[T] {
  def parse(r: Record[T]): Option[Int]
}

// Concrete implementations
class LineRecord[T] extends Record[T]
class FileReader[T](f:File) extends Reader[T] { 
  val lines = Source.fromFile(f).getLines()
  def iterator: Iterator[LineRecord[T]] =
    new Iterator[LineRecord[T]] {
      def next() = new LineRecord[T]
      def hasNext = lines.hasNext
    }
}
trait TypeA
object TypeA {
    implicit object TypeAParser extends Parser[TypeA] {
        def parse(r: Record[TypeA]): Option[Int] = ???
    }
}
trait TypeB
object TypeB {
    implicit object TypeBParser extends Parser[TypeB] {
        def parse(r: Record[TypeB]): Option[Int] = ???
    }
}

// The "app"
object MainApp {
  def process(f: File) =
    records(f) foreach { r => parse(r) }

  def records(f: File) = {
    if(true)
      new FileReader[TypeA](f)
    else
      new FileReader[TypeB](f)   
  }

  def parse[T](r: Record[T])(implicit parser: Parser[T]): Option[Int] =
      parser.parse(r)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off you must import the implicit object in order to use them:

```
import TypeA._
import TypeB._
```

That's not enough though. It seems like you're trying to apply implicits dynamically. That's not possible; they have to be found compile time.

If you import the objects as above and change the records so that the compiler finds the correct generic it will run fine:

```
def records(f: File) = new FileReader[TypeA](f)
```

But then it may not be what you were looking for ;)

Comment: As far as i can see the op's code is intended to realize compile-time polymorphizm based on implicits - it's possible by using type-clasess

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm after. :) You're right though; I am trying to return implicits dynamically... Maybe it's back to the drawingboard!

Comment: @dk14 see the if statement inside `records`. After this, the type parameter is not known until the program is run.

Comment: it's impossible with type classes, assuming flag `true` is not a static constant. By the way dynamical dispatching still possible in runtime with mix-ins - mixed trait can be choosen by flag and contain its own implicit value.

Comment: `new FileReader(f) with TypeA` (for run-time polymorphizm with implicits)

Comment: No, implicit arguments doesn't provide runtime polymorphism, for that you use inheritance or pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

1) Using type with implicit inside as type parameter - doesn't bind this implicit to the host type, to do this change objects to the traits and mix them instead of generalizing (type-parametrizing):

```
  def records(f: File) = {
    if(true)
      new FileReader(f) with TypeA
    else
      new FileReader(f) with TypeB   
  }
```

2) The `parser` should be in scope of function that calls `parse`. So you may try smthg like that:

```
 def process(f: File) = {
     val reader = records(f);
     import reader._
     reader foreach { r => parse(r) }
  }
```

PlanB) Simpler alternative is to define type-parameter specific implicit methods inside the `AppMain` (or some trait mixed in), but it will work only if TypeA/TypeB is known on compile time, so `records` method can return concrete type:

```
implicit class TypeAParser(r: Record[TypeA]) {
    def parse: Option[Int] = ???
}

implicit class TypeBParser(r: Record[TypeB]) {
    def parse: Option[Int] = ???
}

def process[T <: TypeAorB](f: File) =
    records[T](f).foreach(_.parse)

def recordsA[T <: TypeAorB](f: File) =  new FileReader[T](f)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the return type of your `records` method is basically `FileReader[_]` (since it can return either `FileReader[TypeA]` or `FileReader[TypeB]`), and you don't provide an implicit argument of type `Parser[Any]`. If you remove the `if`-expression the return type is inferred to `FileReader[TypeA]`, which works fine. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but obviously the compiler can't select implicit argument based upon a type that is only known at runtime.

Comment: Yup, type `_ >: TypeA with TypeB <: Object` to be exact! I'm basically trying to implement an adapter pattern of sorts. :S

Answer (score 0):

Here is, I think, the full set of modifications you need to do to get where I *think* you want to go.

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.File
import reflect.runtime.universe._

// Core traits
trait Record[+T]
trait Reader[+T] extends Iterable[Record[T]]
trait Parser[-T] {
  def parse(r: Record[T]): Option[Int]
}

// Concrete implementations [unmodified]
class LineRecord[T] extends Record[T]
class FileReader[T](f:File) extends Reader[T] {
  val lines = Source.fromFile(f).getLines()
  def iterator: Iterator[LineRecord[T]] =
    new Iterator[LineRecord[T]] {
      def next() = new LineRecord[T]
      def hasNext = lines.hasNext
    }
}

sealed trait Alternatives
case class TypeA() extends Alternatives
object TypeA {
    implicit object TypeAParser extends Parser[TypeA] {
        def parse(r: Record[TypeA]): Option[Int] = ???
    }
}
case class TypeB() extends Alternatives
object TypeB {
    implicit object TypeBParser extends Parser[TypeB] {
        def parse(r: Record[TypeB]): Option[Int] = ???
    }
}

class ParseAlternator(parserA: Parser[TypeA], parserB: Parser[TypeB]) extends Parser[Alternatives] {
  def parse(r: Record[Alternatives]): Option[Int] = r match {
    case x: Record[TypeA @unchecked] if typeOf[Alternatives] =:= typeOf[TypeA] => parserA.parse(x)
    case x: Record[TypeB @unchecked] if typeOf[Alternatives] =:= typeOf[TypeB] => parserB.parse(x)
  }
}
object ParseAlternator {
  implicit def parseAlternator(implicit parserA: Parser[TypeA], parserB: Parser[TypeB]): Parser[Alternatives] = new ParseAlternator(parserA, parserB)
}

// The "app"
object MainApp {
  import ParseAlternator._
  def process(f: File) =
    records(f) foreach { r => parse(r) }

  def records(f: File): Reader[Alternatives] = {
    if(true)
      new FileReader[TypeA](f)
    else
      new FileReader[TypeB](f)
  }

  def parse[T](r: Record[T])(implicit parser: Parser[T]): Option[Int] =
      parser.parse(r)
}
```

The gist of it is: all of this would be completely classsical if only your `parse` instance did not have to pattern-match on a generic type but dealt directly with an `Alternative` instead.

It's this limitation (inherited from the JVM) that scala can't properly pattern-match on an object of a parametric type that requires the reflection & `typeOf` usage. Without it, you would just have type alternatives for your content (`TypeA`, `TypeB`), which you would add to a `sealed` trait, and which you would dispatch on, in an implicit that produces a `Parser` for their supertype.

Of course this isn't the *only* solution, it's just what I think is the meeting point of what's closest to what you're trying to do, with what's most idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks - You're gonna have to give me a minute to take that in!